# Arm-angstrom gcc compiler skips openCV libs

Tags: eclipse, arm, cross-compiling, angstrom-linux

I'm cross-compiling my first program with OpenCV on the BeagleBone.

I use Eclipse Juno IDE, arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc compiler and the last OpenCV library.
I've successfully built program with OpenCV on my PC, I've successfully cross-compiled "Hello Wolrd" onto my BB, then I've tried to cross-compile OpenCV on BB.

I just linked OpenCV libraries (opencv_highgui, without changing my "hello world" code) and after compiling got the following errors:

```
/usr/local/angstrom/arm/lib/gcc/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/4.3.3/../../../../arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libopencv_highgui.so when searching for -lopencv_highgui
/usr/local/angstrom/arm/lib/gcc/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/4.3.3/../../../../arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libopencv_highgui.a when searching for -lopencv_highgui
/usr/local/angstrom/arm/lib/gcc/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/4.3.3/../../../../arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_highgui
```

Arm compiler ignores this lib, and I don't know why.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Assuming you've compiled opencv for your target. Try to give -L/<where_ever_your_opencv_crosscompile_output_is to gcc.